# jQuery use multiple variables for event handler

Tags: jquery, event-handling

If you have setup two jquery objects to trigger the same event how would you write the event handler using the variable names.

```
var overlay     = content.find('.qv-overlay'),
    close_btn   = content.find('.close_btn');

// Remove Content Container
$('.qv-overlay, .close_btn').on('click', function(e){
    content.remove();
});
```

Something like

```
$(overlay, close_btn).on('click', function(e){
    content.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

[.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched
>   elements.

```
overlay.add(close_btn).on('click', function(e){
    content.remove();
});
```